# PHP require link from root folder

Tags: php

I've searching around and I actually found some topics related, but the suggestions there did not worked for me.

My project folder structure is the following:

```
projectSample (name of folder)

 » backend (folder)
  -> index.php
  -> orders.php
  » Admin (folder)
   -> index.php

 » libs (folder)
  -> config.php
  -> orders.php
  -> global.php

 » views (folder)
  » backend (folder)
   -> header.php
   » content (folder)
    -> index.php
    -> orders.php
    -> unique_order.php
    -> add_order.php
    » admin (folder)
     -> index.php

 » css (folder)
 » js (folder)
```

I have a function inside the file **global.php** called `getLanguageFile()`, which requires the file appropriate.

```
public static function getLanguageFile(){
    $default = 'pt';

    if(isset($_COOKIE['language'])){
        switch($_COOKIE['language']){
            case 'fr': break;
            case 'en_US': $default = 'en'; break;
            case 'es': break;
        }
    }
    $path = rootPath . "/languages/" . $default . ".php";

    return require_once($path);
}
```

I call this function in all files of Backend folder. The variable `rootPath` has the following value in the **config.php** file.

```
define("rootPath", '/projectSample');
```

This does not work and I receive in every page the following error:

> Warning: require_once(/projectSample/languages/pt.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\projectSample\libs\global.php on line 370

But looking at the path, it is actually correct (/projectSample/languages/pt.php) actually exists.
I've tried to adapt other functions to my needs such as:

```
define("rootPath", dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

This one seems to work fine for the `require_onces` function, but not for css/js files.
If I use the same variable for css/js files to include I receive and error on Chrome console:

> Not allowed to load local resource:
>   file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/projectSample/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css

So, using another variable just for css/js seems the best approach but I can't put it worked for all files.

```
define("clientPath", dirname(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])));
```

This variable works fine for » Backend folder (and for all each files), however, it does not work well on the folder Admin.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo clientPath. "/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"; ?>'/>

» backend (folder) > works
 -> index.php > works
 -> orders.php -> works
 » admin (folder) > does not work
  -> index.php > does not work
```

The reason why it does not work in that folders its because the final link is:

```
http://localhost/projectSample/backend/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css
```

And it should be:

```
http://localhost/projectSample/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css
```

Ok, I could create another variable (like the below), but is that the best approach?

```
define("clientPath_admin", dirname(dirname(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))));
```

Sorry for the long topic, and I'm not using `basehref`.

Comment: Just use `require(_once) __DIR__ . '/relative/path/to/current/file/from/current/directory/calling/file/is/in.php';`

Comment: @PeeHaa nice to see i'm not the only one using `__DIR__` which is a stallion.

Comment: @PeeHaa I did not get it. If I use (for example) in the file `View->Backend->Content->Admin->index.php` `require_once(__DIR__ . '/libs/orders.php')` I get an error. `Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\projectsample\views\backend\content\admin/libs/orders.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: `projectsample` vs `projectSample`?

Comment: Also regarding loading your html resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls/21828923#21828923

Comment: Well while copying the error I forgot to change to `projectSample`, it's not that the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is,

Declare, this is the frontend path

```
 define("BASEPATH", "http://localhost/projectSample/");
 define("BASEPATH_TO_ADMIN", "http://localhost/projectSample/backend/");
```

In Html part

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo BASEPATH. "css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"; ?>'/>
```

Comment: Well, like I thought, the only solution is to create multiple variables. Thanks.